For Loop Errors Solved by Splitting Loop Function
I want to iterate over dataframes which have the same number of columns. Each dataframe as an ID column which has different names.
I am dropping any na rows from each df in this column, then wishing to add a new column which indicates the ID type.
The below code produces an error against the last line of the loop:
national_id_dfs = [df1, df2]
column_names = ['df1_ID', 'df2_ID']

for (df, id_col) in zip(national_id_dfs, column_names):
    df = df.dropna(subset=[id_col], inplace=True)
    df['ID Type'] = id_col


TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment

However, splitting the loops as below works as expected.
national_id_dfs = [df1, df2]
column_names = ['df1_ID', 'df2_ID']

for (df, id_col) in zip(national_id_dfs, column_names):
    df = df.dropna(subset=[id_col], inplace=True)

for (df, id_col) in zip(national_id_dfs, column_names):
    df['ID Type'] = id_col

What is the issue with the first for loop?

df = df.dropna(subset=[id_col], inplace=True) should be df.dropna(subset=[id_col], inplace=True)

Voting to close as this is just a typo

I'm struggling to see the typo?

Remove df = , inplace=True acts in place and returns None

But when i split out the for loop, the code is still df = and it works, but it doesn't in the combined 1st loop?

Don't split the loop, just don't reassign to df if you use inplace=True.
